# Function preg_quote works incorrect?

Tags: php, regex

Suppose I want to check input in order to allow Unicode letters and numbers plus configured symbols.

```
$allow_symbols = './*!@%&[]:,-_ ';
// $allow_symbols = '';
$pattern = '/^['.preg_quote($allow_symbols).'\p{L}\p{N}]+$/iu';
print $pattern."\n";
preg_match($pattern, '');
```

Sandbox is here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b99a8f042695d1dc1528834d21e6eb6ad62972e6

I got 
`Warning</b>:  preg_match(): Unknown modifier '\' in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>9</b>`

The problem originates from $allow_symbols, if I override it with empty string as it commented out  - nothing wrong happens. And when I past exactly printed pattern to https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/rxj it works fine.

So, what's the matter and how to deal with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`preg_quote`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) does not escape the regex's [delimiter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) by default, because it can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character.

Set its second parameter (`$delimiter`) to also escape forward slashes:

```php
$escaped_symbols = preg_quote($allow_symbols, '/');
$pattern = "/^[$escaped_symbols\p{L}\p{N}]+$/iu";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [T-Regx library](https://t-regx.com) which [automatically choses delimiters](https://t-regx.com/docs/delimiters) and [handles unsafe characters](https://t-regx.com/docs/handling-user-input):

```
$allow_symbols = './*!@%&[]:,-_ ';

Pattern::prepare(['^[', [$allow_symbols], '\p{L}\p{N}]+$'], 'iu')->match('');
```